# O365 Group name changed but not updating in SharePoint Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365-groups

A Modern SharePoint Online site has been created (with an O365 Group).
SP Members group contains the O365 Members group and SP SC contains the O365 Owners group, as normal.

The O365 group name has been changed and so has the primary email.
The SP Groups still contain the old O365 groups (they have not been refreshed) and  waited 12hrs.

i.e. SP Members group contains the original O365 Members group, so I delete from Site Collection and re-add. This seems to be correct now.

But

SP SC contains the orignal O365 Owners group - I cannot add the renamed O365 Owners group. The people picker only list O365 Members group.
I tried adding the UPN, but this fails too.
I tried SP Admin centre but couldnt find a way to do this either.

If its not changed will it continue to work and is mapped correctly, its just not showing in the UI? Is there a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you update the Microsoft 365 group name, you needn't do anything in SharePoint. If the group name has not yet updated in SharePoint, it will continue to work. SharePoint uses the group's GUID rather than the display name.

Comment: Before your reply I deleted the orignal O365 Owners group in the hope I can add the renamed O365 Owners group, but I cannot add any owner group. The people picker only lists the members group. 
I tried the guid also and appended with _o but it only adds the Members group (though renamed) . Is there an issue with SharePoint not being selective over Owner / Members role when it comes to adding using the 'Site Collection Administrators' dialog box? Perhaps it needs to be resolved with PS?

Comment: You might be able to find the AD group reference in the hidden user list  https://zimmergren.net/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list/ but I would recommend against deleting these OOTB groups when dealing with a group connected sites for this reason.

Comment: Hidden list checked and re-named members O365 Members group present. There should be a way to add Owners to SCA.. This seems an issue that MS has overlooked? Leaving the orginal Owners in SCA will be confusing for any new administrator.

Comment: Even if the owners group in SP doesn't update the name, it's still the same group. There's no reason to change the SCA if you've change the name of the Microsoft 365 group. From the hidden list, you should be able to get the owners group ID and use PowerShell to set it as SCA. Microsoft probably don't support users deleting the group from the SCA when you have a group connected site.

Comment: I have the guid (Assume this is what you mean by 'owners group ID' , using PS it only adds as Members to SCA.

Comment: I'm not sure what can be done if the GUID with the additional _0 doesn't work. I imagine deleting the owners group from the SCA is not supported and end users aren't able to add this themselves. I'm not sure if there's a Graph API endpoint you can try, failing that, you can open a ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

in the admin center,
select the group.
Membership > Site Admins.
If the "owners" group is missing, you should see a button called "add group owners", click this to add the group owners as admins.

The group will display in the admin center and the in the UI with the original group name, not the updated name, i consider this a bug (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/541845/refresh-updated-security-group-name-in-sharepoint?page=1&orderby=Helpful#answers)